# C program array Position

Tags: c

Why does the following C program return the subtraction of 4 of `(a+4)` and 1 of `(a+1)`?

```
     #include<stdio.h>
     int main()
     {

      int a[3][2]={1,2,
                   5,7,
                   6,8};

      printf("\n%d",(a+4)-(a+1));
      return 0;}
```

Also when i substitute the subtraction operator with addition (a+4)+(a+1), it gives

```
error: invalid operands to binary + (have ‘int (*)[2]’ and ‘int (*)[2]’)
```

Comment: By algebra `(a+4)-(a+1)` = a+4-a-1 = a-a+4-1=3`. So you should get an output of 3.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking in the first sentence of your post; can you reword?

Comment: Also, in your hypothetical, why are you adding (a+4) and (a+1)? You're basically adding two memory addresses, which is completely nonsensical and something that you should never do.

Comment: well this question was asked during my interview. So truly, it is nonsensical to me as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that `a` is an array and when used by itself degrades to a pointer (i.e. a memory address). This means that `(a+4)` and `(a+1)` are also memory addresses. Subtracting memory addresses makes sense because you are calculating the distance between the two addresses. However, adding memory addresses is nonsense.

I am unsure what you want to do here, so I am not able to suggest a solution to fix the problem. Feel free to edit your question with more details so that we can help you further.

Comment: Since `a` is 2-dimensional, `*(a+4)` is still an array.

Comment: `a` is two dimensional, though.  What you have there is trying to add arrays.

Comment: And `*(a+4)` is a reference to an object that does not exist. Even evaluating `a+4` is undefined by the C standard.

Comment: @user315052 thanks for the correction. I guess you need to do more to convert the 2D array to a linear one...

Comment: @Eric For some reason I was thinking that `*(a+4)` would continue to the memory location after `a[3]`. In fact, this is most likely the behavior in many implmentations, but thank you for pointing out that it is undefined by the standard.

Comment: `*(a+4)` would point to the fifth row of the array, but there are only 3.

Comment: @teppic Exactly...so most likely it points to the location in memory after that third row, but again the exact behavior is undefined. I removed my `printf()` examples until I can think of a correct suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code and got 3 as the difference, which makes sense: a + 4 - (a + 1) = 3.

On the error, I believe that C doesn't let you add two memory addresses as a safeguard. It's totally nonsensical to do so as I pointed out in a previous comment. Subtracting one memory address from another, however, gives you something useful in certain cases (the offset between two locations in memory).

Answer (score -1):

you have a syntax error.
you r using a as an single intiger, but the data type of a is integer array.
so an e.g subtraction would be: a[1][3]-a[0][3] and the value here equals 3.

(for your info the array actually looks like a={1,2,5
                                                 7,6,8} it has 3 rows and 2 columns.